# How constructor calling occurs in case of c# custom exception handling?

Tags: c#, exception

Here's is my program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        throw new UserAlreadyLoggedInException("Hello");
    }
}

public class UserAlreadyLoggedInException : Exception
{
    public UserAlreadyLoggedInException(string message) : base(message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here");
    }    
}
```

Now, I know that base class constructor runs before derived class constructor. But when I run the above code the output comes out to be

```
     Here
     Unhandled Exception:Testing.UserAlreadyLoggedInException:Hello.
```

How come "Here" is printed before Unhandled.....?

Comment: Not the base constructor prints to the console but the environment which shows the thrown and unhandled exception.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio: debug it by setting a breakpoint at `throw new UserAlreadyLoggedInException("Hello");` and walk through it using F11.

Comment: Does that compiles? `UserAlreadyLoggedInException` class has constructor of `ParentException`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: no, corrected.

Comment: I don't see any exception handling here. You simply create own exception type and then throw it. In that exactly order. So `"Here"` (exception is created) and then "Unhandler exception occurs ..." (because you didn't handle it). What is unclear?

Comment: I thought base constructor is writing Unhandled......:Hello to the console...so, I wondered how come base is executing after the child constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    throw new UserAlreadyLoggedInException("Hello");
  }
}


class LoginException : Exception
{
  public LoginException(string message) : base(message)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("least derived class");
  }
}

class UserAlreadyLoggedInException : LoginException
{
  public UserAlreadyLoggedInException(string message) : base(message)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("most derived class");
  }
}
```

You can also try writing your `Main` method like this:

```
  static void Main()
  {
    var ualie = new UserAlreadyLoggedInException("Hello");
    Console.WriteLine("nothing bad has happened yet; nothing thrown yet");
    throw ualie;
  }
```

So constructing an `Exception` instance with the `new` keyword does not "raise" or "throw" an exception. You need `throw` for that. The `throw` statement works by first evaluating the expression that comes after the `throw` keyword. The result of that evaluation will be a reference to an exception instance. After evaluating the expression, `throw` "throws" the exception referred by the value of the expression.

Your misunderstanding is that the `Exception` "explodes" as soon as the instance constructor to `System.Exception` runs. That is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

You first have to create the exception, before you can be thrown.

1. Creation of the exception instance initiated by `new UserAlreadyLoggedInException`;
2. `UserAlreadyLoggedInException` constructor called;
3. Call to `Console.WriteLine` inside constructor;
4. Constructor done;
5. Throwing of the newly created exception instance;
6. The exception isn't handled, thus the application error handler writes the error to the console.

Comment: @dividedbyzero: What don't you get?

Comment: But in normal inheritance, I think the base class constructor run just immediately after the child constructor is called without executing any of the child constructor code. What about the base(message) won't it do anything.?

Comment: @dividedbyzero: This doesn't have anything to do with inheritance.

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @dividedbyzero: I think the answer does. First you create an exception, and all related code is executed, then you throw it.

Comment: And it is the base(message) that prints "Hello" at the end of  Unhandled Exception:Testing.UserAlreadyLoggedInException:"Hello"

Comment: @dividedbyzero: Yes, `hello` is the message, so it is written on handling the unhandled exception.

Comment: Then when does the base(message) comes into play?

Comment: @dividedbyzero: Never. It just sets the message you pass in in the `Exception.Member` class member.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a try/catch of your own the program flow becomes more apparent. Note that Exception's constructor does not write anything it just stores the message string for later use.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new UserAlreadyLoggedInException("Hello");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My handled exception: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class UserAlreadyLoggedInException : Exception
{
    public UserAlreadyLoggedInException(string message) : base(message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is printed to the console after it has been instantiated and thrown.

The instantiation prints "Here", then the runtime catches it and prints the "Unhandled Exception:" `ToString()` representation.